# Find all entities by given rank

Tags: sql-server, dense-rank

I am trying to understand ranking functions in **T-SQL**, but I am not sure I do. I am practising `DENSE_RANK()` and having troubles with understanding what's happening here:

```
SELECT 
   EmployeeID,
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   Salary,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER
   (PARTITION BY Salary ORDER BY EmployeeID) AS Rank
FROM  Employees
WHERE Salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

[image]

Why columns with equal salaries have a different rank?

> The rows within a partition that have the same values will receive the same rank.

My next question is if it's possible to find only the entities whose **Rank** is 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is correct. You are creating a group based on salary and then order by employee id

I guess you want:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Rank
```

To filter rows you need to use inline view/cte:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
   EmployeeID,
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   Salary,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Rank
FROM  Employees
WHERE Salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Rank = 2
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

*EDIT:*

> Why columns with equal salaries have a different rank?

The issue is that you partitioned data based on salary. Salaries with the same value are in single group. Now for that group ordering is performed by using `employee_id` column which is different per employee.

Without `PARTITION BY` the entire dataset is single partition and ranks are based on descending salary value.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate it but I am not sure I understand how it works. (`DENSE_RANK()`)

Comment: @AndrewRogers I've extended the answer

Answer (score 0):

> Why columns with equal salaries have a different rank?

Try following if you don't want see different RANK for same Salary

```
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary desc) AS Rank,
```

> My next question is if it's possible to find only the entities whose Rank is 2?

You can use either sub-query method or CTE, following is sub-query example

```
select *
from (
SELECT 
   EmployeeID,
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   Salary,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary desc) AS Rank
FROM  Employees
WHERE Salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000
) as t 
where r.rank = 2
```